# Count frequency of a value per column, displaying results for all columns with blanks filled

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql

I have a large SQL database which looks like this:[image: database layout]

For a single column, I would count frequency with the command:

```
SELECT col1,count(1) FROM tbl GROUP BY col1;
```

to give something which looks like this: [image: output for a single column]

But ideally, I would want a command which ran the above over all specified columns, matching on the Value column, and filling the blanks out with 0. Is this possible in any SQL implementation? Im currently using SQLite, but we're in a fairly open relationship.

This is my 'desired' output:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to group by more than one column in one select?

Comment: Yeah i think so - here i've written 'Value' but in the example code that's actually just 'col1'. In the multiple-column version, this would not be a column's value, but a list of the unique values in all columns. I think the solution lies somewhere in finding a list of these unique values, and doing the frequency count during the full table scan, then at the end putting it all together as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using a subquery with `union all`:

```
select col, count(1)
from (
  select col1 col from yourtable
  union all
  select col2 from yourtable
  union all
  select col3 from yourtable
  ) t
group by col
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cdab/2)

---

Given your desired results, perhaps this is what you're looking for instead using an `outer join` with conditional aggregation:

```
select col, 
  sum(case when t1.col1 = col then 1 else 0 end ) as Col1Count,
  sum(case when t1.col2 = col then 1 else 0 end) as Col2Count,
  sum(case when t1.col3 = col then 1 else 0 end) as Col3Count
from (
  select col1 col from yourtable
  union
  select col2 from yourtable
  union
  select col3 from yourtable
  ) t
  left join yourtable t1 on t.col in (t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3)
group by col
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cdab/8)

Comment: This is VERY cool - I can see this being really useful for other kinds of query - but as it sums all values and not per-column it doesn't answer the OP. But still simple, elegant, and everything I love about SQL :)
Also +1 for the Fiddle :D

Comment: @user3329564 -- sorry, misread your desired results.  Updated the answer.

Comment: @user3329564 -- and here's a similar approach with conditional aggregation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cdab/8

Comment: I get different results for the "More Fiddle" and the fiddle in your comment (8cdab/8) - actually the first fiddle gives some really weird results :P
But the example in your last comment is *perfect* ! Can you update your post with that so i can mark it as answered :D

Comment: @user3329564 -- rethinking it through, the multiple outer joins could be causing the duplicates (and therefore, miscalculations).  I've updated to use the conditional aggregation approach.